# Canvas.TextWidth doesn't return the correct value

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am writing to the canvas of a TImage component in delphi.
I am using the Canvas.TextWidth but when I change the font size of the string, this function Canvas.textWidth returns the same values.

I am working on Delphi xe6

Comment: Please include the essential part of the code you are using.

Comment: According to my experience most of the cases an error like this is caused by one of the following reasons: either you are using the wrong canvas or you are passing the wrong string to the function. We can't help you detecting your errors if you don't provide source code. (If you correct your question I'm willing to remove my downvote.)

Comment: I cannot use related button, but here is a helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2548178/1960514. It works in my case.

Comment: Also, it's good to include a question in the post. There's no question, so the answer is "Ah, I see - very interesting" :)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you are using the wrong **Canvas** at some point in your code since there appears to be no unexpected behaviour with a **TImage** **Canvas** in a crude and simple test case.  e.g. drop a **TImage** on a form and add this to the form **OnCreate** event:

```
Image1.Canvas.Font.Size := 10;
Caption := IntToStr(Image1.Canvas.TextWidth('FOO'));

Image1.Canvas.Font.Size := 24;
Caption := Caption + ' should be < ' + IntToStr(Image1.Canvas.TextWidth('FOO'));
```

And you will get a smaller initial **TextWidth** for the smaller **Font.Size**.

Most likely you are setting the **Font.Size** on a different Canvas (the form ?).  Unlike some other components (e.g. **TPanel**) a **TImage** does not "inherit" the **Font** of any parent control or form.

Ensure that your code is consistently working with the correct **Canvas**.