# Get width and height of a string in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there anyway I can get width and height of a string in Pascal Script?

*Eg:*

```pascal
var
  S: String;

S := 'ThisIsMyStringToBeChecked'
```

Here I need to return its height and width according to its current font size and font.

I read [How to get TextWidth of string (without Canvas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2548132/850848), but can't convert it to an Inno Setup Pascal code.

I want this measurements (width and height) to change the `TLabel.Caption` like `'Too Long To Display'` with `clRed` when width of the string of its caption exceeds `TLabel.Width`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for the `TNewStaticText` (not the `TLabel`):

```pascal
type
  TSize = record
    cx, cy: Integer;
  end;

function GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc: THandle; s: string; c: Integer;
  var Size: TSize): Boolean;
  external 'GetTextExtentPoint32W@Gdi32.dll stdcall';
function GetDC(hWnd: THandle): THandle;
  external 'GetDC@User32.dll stdcall';
function SelectObject(hdc: THandle; hgdiobj: THandle): THandle;
  external 'SelectObject@Gdi32.dll stdcall';

procedure SmartSetCaption(L: TNewStaticText; Caption: string);
var
  hdc: THandle;
  Size: TSize;
  OldFont: THandle;
begin
  hdc := GetDC(L.Handle);
  OldFont := SelectObject(hdc, L.Font.Handle);
  GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, Caption, Length(Caption), Size);
  SelectObject(hdc, OldFont);

  if Size.cx > L.Width then
  begin
    L.Font.Color := clRed;
    L.Caption := 'Too long to display';
  end
    else
  begin
    L.ParentFont := True;
    L.Caption := Caption;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Brilliant.........Works well. But I like to know why that won't work with `TLabel`?

Comment: Because `TLabel` is not `TWinControl`, so it does not have `.Handle`. The code for `TLabel` needs to be somewhat different. Maybe, one can use `WizardForm.Handle` instead, or maybe `nil` can be passed to the `GetDC`.