# Creating TCanvas to measure text width

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I want to measure text width of a `TButton` so that I can resize it when the text changes. If the button uses `ParentFont`, I can use the form `Canvas` to get the width:

```
int GetButtonTextWidth(TForm* form, TButton* btn)
{
    const int base = form->Canvas->TextWidth(btn->Caption);
    const int margin = 16;
    return base + margin;
}
```

If the button has different font, for example it is bold, this is not accurate. I tried to create a new `TCanvas`:

```
int GetButtonTextWidth(TForm* form, TButton* btn)
{
    std::unique_ptr<TCanvas> canvas(new TCanvas);
    canvas->Font = btn->Font;
    const int base = canvas->TextWidth(btn->Caption);
    const int margin = 16;
    return base + margin;
}
```

This gives exception: "Canvas does not allow drawing". How do I create a `TCanvas` that allows measuring text width and gives accurate results?

Comment: Create a temporary bitmap, assign the font to the canvas of that bitmap and call `TextWidth()`. [Here is a Delphi example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548178/2292722)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VCL has a [`TControlCanvas`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControlCanvas) class for associating a Canvas with a UI control.

```cpp
int GetButtonTextWidth(TButton* btn)
{
    std::unique_ptr<TControlCanvas> canvas(new TControlCanvas);
    canvas->Control = btn;
    canvas->Font = btn->Font;
    const int base = canvas->TextWidth(btn->Caption);
    const int margin = 16;
    return base + margin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a handle to the canvas in order to use `TCanvas::TextWidth()`. So changing your code to

```
int GetButtonTextWidth(TForm* form, TButton* btn)
{
    std::unique_ptr<TCanvas> canvas(new TCanvas);
    canvas->Handle = form->Canvas->Handle;
    canvas->Font = btn->Font;
    const int base = canvas->TextWidth(btn->Caption);
    const int margin = 16;
    return base + margin;
}
```

should work.